# Partial New Email Address Generating Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

What can I do with Selenium IDE if I want to create a test case for signing up and I need the same first name, a different last name each time, and an email address like first_name+last_name@gmail.com ? Appreciate your efforts.
I have some signing up test cases, and so I have like 6 path from where I can sign in. Obviously, each time I do I need a new email address. The structure of the mail address must look like this qa+testNumber@gmail.com . So qa+ and the @gmail.com must remain the same for all, but testNumber must increase with one for , kind of (test++) each test case. Like qa+test1@gmail.com, qa+test2@gmail.com, qa+test3@gmail.com . I think the last name can be the same always, except the email address which must be a new one each time. Do you have any clue how can I solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could use a little more detail, such as what you mean by "a different last name each time".  I assume this a form entry but what actually do you want to test?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have some signing up test cases, and so I have like 6 path from where I can sign in. Obviously, each time I do I need a new email address. The structure of the mail address must look like this qa+testNumber@gmail.com . So qa+ and the @gmail.com must remain the same for all, but testNumber must increase  with one for , kind of (test++) each test case. Like qa+test1@gmail.com, qa+test2@gmail.com, qa+test3@gmail.com . I think the last name can be the same always, except the email address which must be a new one each time. Do you have any clue how can I solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should update the question itself with these details.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up running Selenium junit tests in java you can do it very easily with a for() loop? Also gives you much more versatility in what you can actually test =] It's pretty easy to get your head round!

```
for(int i = 0; i < max_number_of_tests; i++;) {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000"); // 30 seconds
    selenium.type("path_to_first_name_input", "QA");
    selenium.type("path_to_last_name_input", "test" + i);
    selenium.type("path_to_email_input", "QA_test" + i + "@test.com");
    selenium.click("path_to_submit_button");
}
```

Might not help you immediately but it will in the long run!

Hope you (or someone) found this useful